# When was this song first presented? (Город Детства by Эдиты Пьехи)

Tags: backstory

I found this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukiNvFHLQF0
where it says 1966 but I wonder whether it has been published earlier.
Город Детства by Эдиты Пьехи

Is somebody able to search russian web for that information? My russian not good enough for that.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Hah! I don't know Russian, but I know this song!  It is a Russian version of "Greenfields," as made famous by The Brothers Four, recorded in 1960. I have a video of them performing it on the old Sing Along with Mitch TV show in that year.

Amusingly, if you type the Russian information provided under the video into Google translate, the title comes out as "City of Childhood," but the songwriter's names (transliterated) are indeed phonetic versions of two of the actual writers of "Greenfields":

Ф. Миллер = F[rank] Miller

Р. Джилкинсон = P Dzilkhinson = (a Russian mispronunciation of) Terry Gilkyson.

Why the Russians did this song, and what the Russian lady is actually singing, are beyond my ken. But if it's the song itself you're after, that's where it came from.

Comment: This is correct - this is a Russian rendition of Greenfields. On why they would do it - socialist regime often rejected anything coming from West, since west was believed to be the source of all immoral things and sins. So singers often went on and made a cover in their mother tongue with same melody that then could pass the censorship. There are A LOT of english covers in Russian and also Serbo-croat/Slovenian language.